# >My counter is counting genotypic combination occurences more than once, how do I ensure it counts one combination and doesnt count it again?

Tags: python, genomics, covid-19, sars-cov-2, mutations

```
mutations = ['A222V', 'D614G', 'E484Q', 'E780Q', 'G476S', 'L18F', 'N439K',
             'S477', 'S477N', 'T478I', 'V483A']

combinations = []
for M in range(1, len(mutations)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(mutations, M):
        combinations.append(subset)
        
        combinations = ['_'.join(sorted(x)) for x in combinations]
        combinations = [x.split('_') for x in list(set(combinations))]

root = "C:"

os.chdir(root)

lineages = os.listdir('Results')

combination_labels = []
combination_counts = []

for lineage in lineages:
    
    df = pd.read_csv('Results/' + lineage).dropna()
    
    for combination in combinations:
    
            combination_df = df[list(df)]
        
            for mutation in combination:
                combination_df = combination_df[combination_df[mutation] == 1]
    
        #print(combination_df.shape[0])
        
            combination_labels.append('_'.join(combination))
            combination_counts.append(combination_df.shape[0])
        
            out_df = pd.DataFrame({'combination':combination_labels,
                               'count':combination_counts})
            out_df['percentage'] = (out_df['count'] / df.shape[0]) * 100
            out_df = out_df.sort_values('percentage', ascending = False)   
        
            out_df.to_csv('Results_2/' + lineage.replace(".csv", "") + '_3.csv',
                     header = True, 
                     index = False)
```

The input CSV

```
lineage,A222V,D614G,E484Q,E780Q,G476S,L18F,N439K,S477,S477N,T478I,V483A
417941,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Output CSV

```
combination,count,percentage
D614G,87355,90.7084929856806
```

My above code is used to count all occurences of combinations of spike protein mutations

- to determine the genotypes.
  However, looking at the values processed into the .csv file, i can see ' D614G' is being counted even when
  it is in combination with other combinations.

My question is how do i ensure once something has been counted (a row in the imported .csv file)
it is not counted for a second time?

OR possibly how can I edit this code to prevent counting of singular mutations even when presented within a combination?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nice to see a traditional python question based on pandas. The top of your code is chopped off. Could you inset it please?

Comment: Could you also add what a row in your CSV looks like?

Comment: Input / output csv?

Comment: The input CSV in your Result folder is only two lines per file?

Comment: The input file has about 97,000 lines of data - each for a strain of SARSCOV2. The output file has around 54 lines, as genotypes but this should be quite a few less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so there are a number of problematic patterns in your code - as far as I understand what you are trying to do. Next time, try to post a reproducible example that people can use and more people will be willing to help.

#### L18-21:

```py
combination_labels = []
combination_counts = []

for lineage in lineages:
```

Declaring these two lists *before* the loop, then appending all your combination labels inside the loop means that these two lists will contain all labels and counts for all runs (all your lineages). If I am understanding your intentions correctly this is probably not something you want. The simple fix here is to just move them into the for-loop.

#### L29-30:

```py
for mutation in combination:
    combination_df = combination_df[combination_df[mutation] == 1]
```

Here you are iteratively checking if the value for each mutation is set to '1', but you are also *overwriting* your `combination_df` variable at each iteration of the loop. After this loop, `combination_df` will be whatever mutation last was set to '1' in your current combination. I will get back to solving this in my solution below.

#### L37-44:

```py
combination_labels.append('_'.join(combination))
combination_counts.append(combination_df.shape[0])

out_df = pd.DataFrame({'combination':combination_labels,
                   'count':combination_counts})
out_df['percentage'] = (out_df['count'] / df.shape[0]) * 100
out_df = out_df.sort_values('percentage', ascending = False)   

out_df.to_csv('Results_2/' + lineage.replace(".csv", "") + '_3.csv',
         header = True, 
         index = False)
```

Since this part is again scoped inside the for-loop, each iteration (each combination) will overwrite the same `'Results_2/' + lineage.replace(".csv", "") + '_3.csv'` file. This you also want to move out of the `for combination in ...` loop.

---

A big concern is also performance. You have 2000-something combinations and 100,000 lines in your file. As you loop over combinations, you also process the DataFrame each time, when this is a proble you can solve in one iteration. It's not much data so it's still fine, but these habits are still good to develop early.

Now here's an idea for a rewrite that should work better. I don't have a csv from you to test with, so there might (proabably are) still things to fix, but hopefully it'll give you a starting point:

```py
mutations = ['A222V', 'D614G', 'E484Q', 'E780Q', 'G476S', 'L18F', 'N439K',
             'S477', 'S477N', 'T478I', 'V483A']

combinations = []
for M in range(1, len(mutations)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(mutations, M):
        combinations.append(subset)  
        
combinations = ['_'.join(sorted(x)) for x in combinations]

root = "C:"

os.chdir(root)

lineages = os.listdir('Results')

for lineage in lineages:

    out_df = pd.DataFrame({"Count": 0}, index=combinations)
    
    df = pd.read_csv('Results/' + lineage, index_col="lineage").dropna()
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        combination = '_'.join(sorted(df.columns[row==1]))
        out_df.loc[combination, "Count"] += 1

    out_df['Percentage'] = (out_df['Count'] / df.shape[0]) * 100
    out_df = out_df.sort_values('Percentage', ascending = False)   

    out_df.to_csv('Results_2/' + lineage.replace(".csv", "") + '_3.csv', header = True, 
        index = True)
```

Comment: Absolutely amazingly detailed reply, thank you so much! It's worked exactly how I needed it! Not sure how to mark this as answered, as I'm very new to this forum - perhaps a mod could help here?
Thank you again, sincerely!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) might help you with that